# Getting value from different div is pressed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value from a div pressed. It works if I use id but not class, and I don't want to spam the same line with minor differences. I want to keep the code minimal and I am new to js.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function test(){
        var ai = document.getElementsByClassName('h').getAttribute('value');
        alert(ai)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="1" onclick="test()">1</div>
    <div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="2" onclick="test()">2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event object to realize which element has pressed (event.target), then get any attribute from the pressed element.

```js
function test(event) {
  const value = event.target.getAttribute('value');
  alert(value)
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="1" onclick="test(event)">1</div>
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="2" onclick="test(event)">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist. To retrieve some value for the clicked element, pass `this` to the function call. Also `value` only works with input elements. To get the `value` property from a div, use `getAttribute("value")`.

```js
function test(el) {
  alert(el.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="1" onclick="test(this)">1</div>
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="2" onclick="test(this)">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use an event handler. You no longer need the click event in your HTML element.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".h"); //Get all elements with class "h"

elems.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() { //Add Event Listener to element
    alert(this.getAttribute("value")); //Read and output attribute
  })
});
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="1">1</div>
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" class="h" value="2">2</div>
```